# Standard input in Java vs command line

Tags: java, stream, operating-system

While every command line process in operating system may use standard input, standard output and standard error data streams, I am confused about command line arguments and standard input.

Maybe my understanding is incorrect. but to me it looks like the standard input is another way to get data into the program in addition to command line. I would be grateful if you help me in understanding the difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Command-line arguments are the main function's arguments. Standard input can be a keyboard or file stream that piped from CLI.

Comment: System.in is standard input, usually the console. System.out is standard output. System.err is standard error.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference (under Linux at least) considering handling of standard input for Java versus any other program.  Standard input in the JVM is inherited from the parent's standard input.   And "the command line" is not the same concept.

Consider `someProg arg1 arg2 <file` in Linux: standard input is the named file, which is not the command line.

All processes get started with a command line; in this case it contains `someProg arg1 arg2`.  By the time the process starts, the command line has been set up; it is what it is, from the point of view of the started process.

Standard input, by contrast, is an input file (identified by descriptor) from which input can be read as desired by the program. By default it's the console, but as shown, the parent process (in this case the shell) can redirect it (in this case, to read from the file named `file`).

One thing to note about programming in Java, though, is that the program being run is really Java (the JVM) itself.  Some of the command line is intended for the JVM, other parts are for the program written in Java.  Java documentation will distinguish the two.

Comment: Thank you. So can I assume that the whole command line (like "java -jar MyProg.jar") is actually the standard input of the shell? Is it the shell that parses the command line and starts the program (here, java) as another process?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass some values from the command line to your C programs when they are executed. These values are called command line arguments and many times they are important for your program especially when you want to control your program from outside instead of hard coding those values inside the code.

The command line arguments are handled using main() function arguments where argc refers to the number of arguments passed(integer mainly) , and argv[] is a pointer array which points to each argument passed to the program(character array/ string mainly) . Following is a simple example which checks if there is any argument supplied from the command line and take action accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Command line input is used when your application is required to run with immediate input, for example in java you write like this:

```java
// CommandLineArgument.java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommandLineArgument {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Please provide exactly one file name as a command line argument.");
            return;
        }

        String filename = args[0];

        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(fileScanner.nextLine());
            }

            fileScanner.close();
            System.out.println("File contents printed successfully!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: File not found: " + filename);
        }
    }
}
```

and you run this program like this:

```bash
javac CommandLineArgument.java && java CommandLineArgument.java /path/to/file.txt
```

As you see whole program is built around one thing, read a file, and so that would be better if we run the program right away with file, instead of run program and then after make program wait for file, give path to the file from **Standard Input** like that:

```java
// StandardInputProgram.java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StandardInputProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
        String filename = scanner.nextLine();

        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(fileScanner.nextLine());
            }

            fileScanner.close();
            System.out.println("File contents printed successfully!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: File not found: " + filename);
        }
    }
}
```

In other cases, I think Standard Input more suitable for handling inputs to the program.